# Should either be followed with a single or plural noun?

Tags: pronouns

Which statement is correct?

This figure does not appear in either textbook.
OR
This figure does not appear in either textbooks.

Comment: The first one is correct. Either + singular.

Answer (score 1):

In the above examples, "either" is used as a definite determiner (more specifically, a definite disjunctive determiner) to indicate two possibilities.

---

From [Cambridge Dictionary's English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/either):

> ***Either* referring to two choices or possibilities**
>
> We can use either as a determiner before a noun to talk about two choices or possibilities. The noun that follows either must be a singular countable noun:
>
> - *Personally, I don’t like either jacket.*
> - Not: … <s>I don’t like either jackets</s>.

---

Think about it this way: what we're actually talking about is one set that is the union of the two options.

On the other hand, "either of" can be followed by a plural noun, so it would be acceptable to say:

> The figure does not appear in either of the textbooks.

---

[Cambridge Dictionary's English Grammar Today](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/either):

> ***Either of***
>
> Either must be followed by of if we use it before the, these, those or
> possessives (my, your) with a plural noun:
>
> - *Either of the children can come with us; we don’t mind which.*
> - *I don’t want either of my parents to know I’ve lost my job.*
> - Not: <s>I don’t want either my parents</s> …